# Does a neural network exist that can learn every possible training data?

Tags: neural-networks, computational-learning-theory, universal-approximation-theorems

The [universal approximation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_approximation_theorem) states, that a feed-forward network with a single hidden layer containing a finite number of neurons can approximate continuous functions on compact subsets of $R^n$.

[Michael Nielsen states](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap4.html)

> No matter what the function, there is guaranteed to be a neural network so that for every possible input, $x$, the value $f(x)$ (or some close approximation) is output from the network.

So, for continuous functions, this seems plausible. Interestingly, in the same article, Nielsen mentioned "any function".

Later, he writes

> However, even if the function we'd really like to compute is discontinuous, it's often the case that a continuous approximation is good enough.

The last statement leaves open a gap, to ask how well an approximation practically can be.

Let's ignore contradictory input/output training pairs like $f(0)=0$ and $f(0)=1$, which actually don't event represent a function anyway.

Furthermore, assume that the training data is generated randomly, which would practically result in a discontinuous function.

How does a neural network learn such data? Will a learning algorithm always be able to find a neural network that approximates the function represented by the input-output pairs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The branch of AI research that answers questions like this is called [computational learning theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_learning_theory).

For the specific question you have asked, the universal approximation theorem does indeed prove that any function can be modeled by a sufficiently wide neural network. The definition of a function includes the requirement that each input be mapped to exactly one output, so contradictory labels in training data are excluded explicitly.

Here is a rough sketch that can provide an intuition behind why this is true. This is not a proper proof, but it gives you an idea of the power of "finite number of neurons" in a hidden layer:

1. A single neuron can essentially learn to draw a straight line across the space of input features. It outputs a value arbitrarily close to 1 for things on one side of the line, and arbitrarily close to 0 for things on the other side of the line.
2. For any given datapoint, it is possible to enclose the hyper-volume containing that datapoint, and *no others* by drawing a series of lines in the input space, and defining one side of each line as "inside" the hyper-volume, and the other side as "outside". In 2-d space, this corresponds to drawing the 4 sides of a square around a point.
3. An output neuron learns to draw lines across the outputs of the hidden layer neurons. It can therefore decide to output 1 only when, say, 4 other neurons are all simultaneously active.

It should seem natural then that a sufficiently wide neural network can *memorize* all of an input pattern. Since memorization is sufficient for "learning" to fit a pattern this should give you an intuition for the ability of neural networks to fit things.